# Should Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchSendAuxRecord have any effect in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am migrating a .NET 4.6 application to .NET Core 3.1.
The application makes a TLS 1.0 connection to a legacy device that is not going to receive any updates (it doesn't support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2)

The issue that I'm facing is related to a mitigation introduced in https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3155464/ms16-065-description-of-the-tls-ssl-protocol-information-disclosure-vu

The workaround that I had in .NET 4.6 was to set the AppContext switch to true:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchSendAuxRecord" , true);
```

This switch does not seem to be doing anything in .NET Core 3.1.The communication to the device breaks as it does not know how to handle the mitigation (Mitigation is to split the first application data to 1 byte then send the remaining data).

Would it be possible to disable the mitigation in .NET Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchSendAuxRecord" , true);
```

is not supported in .NET Core (currently 3.1) According to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31660#issuecomment-581520442

From the link:

> There is not. In general, .NET Core doesn't have those AppContext or registry key switches to temporarily turn off security fixes (such as SCH_SEND_AUX_RECORD) that .NET Framework did.